# Compare two dates in Bash in MAC OSX

Tags: bash, macos, date

I'm new to Bash, apologies in advance.

---

**Set-up**

I have a particular end date `end` which depends on a particular starting date `s` and a period length `p` such that, `end=s+p`.

---

**Problem**

I want to execute a command if and only if today's date is before or equal to the end date.

That is: execute command iff `date ≤ end`.

---

**Code**

```
s='20/09/2017'
p='1'
end=$( date -j -v +"$p"d -f "%d/%m/%Y" "$s")

if [[ date < “$end” ]];
then
   echo 'ok'
fi
```

There are 2 things not the way they should be,

1. `p=1` implies `end = '21/09/2017'` < `date = '26/09/2017'`, but still I get an `ok`.
2. I use `date < “$end”` but I want `date ≤ “$end”`

How to correct 1 and 2?

Comment: I see you have fancy curly quotes in there. Be careful about that. You want plain 0x22 and 0x27 quotes

Comment: I found out today the difference between `”` and `"`. Not sure how to type `"`on my keyboard though... :(

Comment: You need to use a text editor that does not insert "smart" quotes.

Comment: Inside `[[`, the quotes in this particular instance are optional anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your:

   ```
   end=$( date -j -v+"$p"d -f "%d/%m/%Y" "$s" )
   ```

   does not produce what you expect:

   ```
   echo "$end"
   Thu Sep 21 14:40:54 CEST 2017
   ```

   What you expect can be obtained with:

   ```
   end=$( date -j -v+"$p"d -f "%d/%m/%Y" "$s" +"%d/%m/%Y" )
   ```
2. Your comparison:

   ```
   if [[ date < “$end” ]]; then
   ```

   does not behave as you think. `date` is not expanded as the result of the invocation of the `date` command. So, your comparison is a string comparison (`<` in the `[[.]]` conditional expression context) between string `"date"` and string `"Thu Sep 21 14:40:54 CEST 2017"`. You should use something like:

   ```
   date=$( date )
   if [[ "$date" < “$end” ]]; then
   ```

   instead (but using `date` as a variable name is probably not a very good idea).
3. As noticed by the other answers, the date format you chose is not the best for comparisons. So, combining the various fixes with the other wise suggestions, you could try something like:

   ```
   s='20170920'
   p='1'
   end=$( date -j -v+"$p"d -f "%Y%m%d" "$s" +"%Y%m%d" )
   now=$( date +"%Y%m%d" )
   if (( now <= end )); then
      echo 'ok'
   fi
   ```

   Note: `if (( now <= end )); then` is an arithmetic comparison and it should work in this specific case. Note also that it uses `now` and `end`, not `$now` and `$end`: the `((.))` arithmetic comparison interprets variable **names** as the integer value stored in the variable. Anyway, using dates, even in `YYYYmmdd` format, as if they were integers is not that clean. Using UNIX timestamps, which should be OK at least until [year 2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem), is probably cleaner:

   ```
   s='20170920'
   p='1'
   end=$( date -j -v+"$p"d -f "%Y%m%d" "$s" +"%s" )
   now=$( date +"%s" )
   if (( now <= end )); then
      echo 'ok'
   fi
   ```

   because here `now` and `end` are number of seconds since [the Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), that is, true integers. Note, however, that the result could be different from that of the previous solution because you have now a one-second accuracy instead of one-day. Chose which one corresponds to your needs.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation is spot-on.

Comment: Ooops, sorry, I forgot this last aspect. Guess what? In arithmetic expressions you use `<=` for less or equal... Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

When you format the date like `YYYYMMDD` you can simply use an alphanumeric comparison:

```
start=$(date +'%Y%m%d')
end=$(date +'%Y%m%d')

# -gt means greater than - for example.
# check `help test` to get all available operators
if [ $start -gt $end ] ; then ...
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to use a date format which is lexicographical, meaning the big units come first.  I highly recommend the ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD or YYYYMMDD.  Second, `<=` can be written as `-le` (less or equal).