# MacOS bash script not honoring double quotes

Tags: bash, macos, scripting

I have a build script in which I'm trying to copy a file into a directory with spaces. My code works fine when the line is written as such:

```
cp test.png My\ Program.app/Contents/Resources
```

but when it's instead written as:

```
cp test.png “My Program.app/Contents/Resources”
```

...it fails with an error:

```
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory
```

What's wrong?

Comment: First step in shell script trouble-shooting: Add `set -x` to the top of the script to show the commands run.

Comment: OK, I'm getting close... after adding "set -x" I figured out that the problem is that there are spaces in my app name, and enclosing the whole thing in double quotes doesn't work in the script (but it works when typed directly in Terminal). I'm trying a few different things now...

Comment: Are your quotes actually `“` (as in your question) or actually `"` (as bash expects quotes)?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, many native-MacOS text editors by default automatically replace regular quotes with smart ones unless [the relevant "feature" is explicitly turned off](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136402/how-to-disable-smart-quotes). Having "smart quotes" instead of plain-ASCII quotes is thus not particularly unusual on that platform, for folks who are using text editors that aren't specialized programmers' editors.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm asking because often the quotes are correct in the code/terminal, but writing them into an answer turns them into smart quotes.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, in this case, the answer by the OP (and the now-largely-deleted comment thread that led to it) makes it clear that that really was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `set -x` at the beginning of the script helped me see what was happening and identify the problem.

The problem was that there were spaces in the app bundle name (e.g. "My Program"), and enclosing the path in single or double quotes didn't work -- *because the text editor I was using changed double quotes into smart quotes*.

What also worked was **escaping the spaces with a backslash**, like this:

---

GOOD:

```
cp -f myfile My\ Program.app/Contents/Resources
```

---

GOOD (but be careful; some MacOS text editors may change this to the later, BAD form automatically):

```
cp -f myfile "My Program.app/Contents/Resources"
```

---

BAD (due to the quotes being "smart quotes" instead of plain ASCII quotes):

```
cp -f myfile “My Program.app/Contents/Resources”
```

To explain why: Because the shell only sees regular ASCII quotes as quote characters, this gets interpreted as five arguments, instead of the intended four:

```
  cp -f myfile '“My' 'Program.app/Contents/Resources”'
# ^^ ^^ ^^^^^^  ^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# |  |    |      |                  |
# 1  2    3      4                  5
```

...and since `cp` only accepts more than two non-option positional arguments when the last one is a directory, but `Program.app/Contents/Resources”` is not a directory that actually exists, it throws a usage error.

Comment: "Some text editors in MacOS replace ASCII quotes with smart quotes automatically, and those definitely won't work. – Charles Duffy" BINGO. That was it.

Comment: @RobC - I updated my answer accordingly, explaining that it is "bad" only if the editor changes the quotes to smart quotes. I think something like this can happen to others if they use the common text editor app to edit a small bash file, as I did. In other words, it wasn't really a typo, it was a situation that may reoccur to others. My problem is solved and won't happen again, but I'd say that it may happen to others. Perhaps the title of the post could be amended to reflect the real problem though. Suggestions?

Comment: Hmm. We've had other problems with the same root cause -- another one is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46426691/compare-two-dates-in-bash-in-mac-osx -- but right now I'm not sure that there's a good canonical instance of the question.

Comment: BTW, over at [apple.se], they've got a Q&A entry with instructions on disabling smart quotes: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136402/how-to-disable-smart-quotes

Comment: The first two screenshots in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373113/always-enable-smart-quotes-in-textedit) over at _Ask Different_ show where "Smart quotes"  can be disabled in both _"Text Edit"_ preferences, and System-level keyboard preferences.