# Compare two dates in shell/bash script and find days difference

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a date in string format and I want to compare it with the current date and find the difference in days.

```
str1='Fri May 06 02:46:25 IST 2016'
```

Goal: find the difference in days between current date and `str1`.

```
>>>echo $(date)
>>>Tue Aug 25 18:09:50 IST 2020
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
difference() {
   date_one=$(date -d "$1" +%s)
   date_two=$(date -d "$2" +%s)
   echo $(( (date_one - date_two) / 86400 )) days
}

difference 'Fri May 06 02:46:25 IST 2016' $(date)
- 1572 days
```

`"$1"` = capture x argument

`-d` = display time described by string, from input

`+%s` = transform passed date to epoch time to get as integers

Once in epochs we calculate the seconds of difference and divide by `86400`, which is how many seconds in one day, to calculate the number of days between the dates.

Comment: This solution assumes you have GNU `date`, which is generally true on Linux, but less generally elsewhere. POSIX does not have a standard shell command for converting dates, but the BSD (and thus e.g. MacOS) `date` utility lets you do this with a different syntax; see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46426691/compare-two-dates-in-bash-in-mac-osx